# Process.Start starts a shell then quickly exits

Tags: c#, winforms, input, process, streamwriter

I am writing a C# application that uses WinForms.

I want to launch my own shell as an Admin then use Stream Writer to run some commands.

I am not doing any thing malicious. It's to fix the connection issues with another internal application (for work). The other team isn't willing to fix their program so they provided us with a command line fix. However I have to run this on many PC's so I am learning C# and trying to build something that I would use.

As soon as myProcess.Start executes, a black box appears then quickly disappears before going to the next line.

```
  public void ProcessStartAsAdmin(string command)
{
    string cname = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;

    Process myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\CMD.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = @"runas";
    //myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.Start();

    StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;

    String inputText;
    string resetConnection = "C:\\APP\\application.exe /reset /server:example.com /uid:" + cname + " /pwd:" + textBoxPassword.Text.Trim();

    myStreamWriter.WriteLine(resetConnection);

    myStreamWriter.Close();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
    myProcess.Close();

}
```

If I am doing anything wrong, please let me know. If I can use a better technique, I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Set "CreateNoWindow" to false in the start info.

Comment: @LordTakkera i just tried that and same thing. It closes on start up.

Comment: Start cmd with a .bat file and use /k

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did that as well. Same results

Comment: It works fine if you do it right. Keep trying.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you have sample code? How is the code that I posted wrong? Your feedback doesn't seem to be constructive and appears to be of a trolling nature

Comment: `cmd /k` is well documented. It creates a new cmd process and remains open when it has finished processing its instructions.

Comment: You seem to have gone quiet. What's next?

Answer (score 2):

> string resetConnection = "C:\\APP\application.exe

`\a` is illegal. You should write `\\` (it seems you know it, and missed).

Edit:

The screen that your see is empty, because of you chose to redirect output.

What is probably happening is that the line has some error (or it's running time is very small), and you not see that.

Cancel temporary the output redirection, and the process closing, and see what happened.

Comment: Is this an answer? I'm highly doubt this is causing his problem.

Comment: That's enough to supply his problem.

Comment: I tried your suggestion too and thank you for finding an error. But it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I commented out the line for output redirection and same thing happened. I also commented the StandardError too

Comment: @softwareisfun Comment the `myStreamWriter.Close();` too. This is necessary for the cmd not close.

Comment: Tried that as well and same thing. It closes as soon as myProcess.Start executes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is the only issue, but there's no space between these two arguments:

```
/uid:" + cname + "/pwd:"
```

it should be:

```
/uid:" + cname + " /pwd:"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at how you initialize the start info:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = @"runas";
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

You are redirecting the standard input, output and error streams. The documentation for this says:

> You must set UseShellExecute to false if you want to set RedirectStandardOutput to true. Otherwise, reading from the StandardOutput stream throws an exception.

And likewise for the other two standard streams. So, redirection implies that you must set `UseShellExecute` to `false`.

On the other hand, you wish the new process to be elevated. Which means that you want to use the `runas` verb.

The documentation does not say so, but the `Verb` property only has impact when `UseShellExecute` is set to `true`. So, requesting elevation implies that you must set `UseShellExecute` to `true`. There is no other way to request elevation for a new process. You have to pass through the `ShellExecuteEx` (or its relatives) with the `runas` verb and that forces you to set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

So there are two conflicting requirements here. You've got no option at all over elevation I presume. You must elevate for this task. Which means you'll have to give up on redirection. I suppose the only other option would be for you to run the calling process elevated. That would mean that any child processes would also be elevated and there would be no need for `runas` and so you could set `UseShellExecute` to `false`.

However, I see no reason for redirection. You are only doing that, I think, so that you can send commands to the `cmd` process. Instead you can pass the commands as arguments, or place them in an external .bat or .cmd file. So if I were you I would stop redirecting, and set `UseShellExecute` to `true`, and take it from there.